# Fluent NHibernate: the entity '(method name)' doesn't have an Id mapped.

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

This is my first time trying Fluent NHibernate and Auto mapping. Unfortunately I have run into an issue that I cannot get past. I'm getting an error saying that a method on one of my classes cannot be mapped.

```
public class Person 
{
   public IEnumerable<string> GetStuff(){return stuff;}
}
```

The Exception Message is:

```
The entity '<GetStuff>d__0' doesn't have an Id mapped.
```

I even tried adding an IAutoMappingOverride to ignore the method (using map.IgnoreProperty).

Is it really trying to map a method? whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by manually marking each Entity with an interface.

```
public class MyAutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (IEntity));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every entity that you want to Automap must have an Id property, or inherit from a class that has an Id property.  Your Person class does neither.

Also, in my experience, all public methods in entities must be declared **virtual** (though this may not be required if you eager load everything).

Comment: The Person entity isn't the problem, read the exception Message. I didn't include the full person definition because I wanted to keep it simple. I also tried adding virtual to the GetStuff method, but that did not help.

Comment: I saw the message, and it doesn't make any sense to me.  Have no idea why FNH would treat a method as an entity, or what d__0 is.  And it does complain about a missing ID, which was consistent with your sample code, so thought it might be worth a shot.  Glad to hear you solved it - that's a new approach for me.